# Time complexity of standard semidefinite programming solvers

Tags: ds.algorithms, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

I am interested in exact scaling of the ellipsoid method and interior point methods for solving SDPs.

(I am not interested in algorithms like multiplicative weights updates method.)

Comment: See some related questions:  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14770/1542 and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14548/1542

Comment: actually the ellipsoid method and combinatorial primal-dual algorithms are the *only* ways I know how to solve *some* exponential size mathematical programs.

Comment: combinatorial primal-dual is a large class :). do you count mult-weight-update in that class as well ?

Comment: @Suresh, true :). I had multiplicative weights (or Plotkin-Shmoys-Tardos) and Edmonds' blossom algorithm in mind as examples.